# Obtaining conformational energy from Newman projections in first place

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

In this [source](https://www.cpp.edu/~psbeauchamp/pdf/314_conformations.pdf), the conformational energy from Newman projections is obtained. Is there a formula or quantum chemistry approach to obtain the values in first place (pretend that I don't know the source)?

Comment: This has 3 votes for homework and 1 vote for too broad. I don't particularly agree with either, but I do think it's very unclear what you're asking. If you know the "energy cost" of each gauche interaction or eclipsing interaction, then it is a simple matter of adding these up to get what can be loosely described as the total energy of the conformer. Is the question about how to add them up, or is it about how to obtain those values in the first place?

Comment: @orthocresol The question has been modified. I want to know how to obtain the values in first place.

Comment: @Mithoron Unfortunately, it is not a homework question.

Comment: @orthocresol well, I guess I should have voted it "unclear as you are asking" but my first interpretation was that it was about the origin of the energy values, and that it therefore was "too broad". I recommend either contacting the author of that document or looking for associated documents, or basic literature including textbooks. Relative energies of different conformers can in some cases be obtained experimentally (by measuring populations spectroscopically) and estimated theoretically using QM.